# df.plot(x='Datetime',y='calls',) is being stubborn. I have thrown everything I know (which isnt much) at it

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I am trying create a simple line graph using "X" axis as date/time; "Y" as number of calls. I have fix a few syntax errors along the way (I am extremely new to python) as I inherited a position at work. My predecessor didnt leave anything to help and the code I am running mostly comes from his notes.

This is the error
13 df.plot(x='Datetime',y='calls',) # figure.gca means "get current axis"

**This is the entire code**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
pl.xticks(rotation = 90)
headers = ['calls','date','time']
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\cbordelon\\Documents\\Python\\testcr1.csv',parse_dates=     {"Datetime" : [1,2]},names=headers)
#pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
#df.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['Date'],r['Time']),)
print (df)
#f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
df.plot(x='Datetime',y='calls') # figure.gca means "get current axis"
df.Datetime=pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df.set_index('Datetime')
df['calls'].plot()
plt.title('calls over year', color='black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit1:
I tried df=df.astype(float) before .plot and nothing changed so I assume that my csv is reading correctly.
Edit2:
Correcting code per Raphael suggestions
Edit 3:
Now I am getting "No numeric data to plot" Damn this is frustrating.

Comment: There is a trailing comma in line 13, which might be an issue. also plt.show() does not need the underscore

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, however, it did not plot out the graph.

Comment: What kind of plot are you trying to create? Does it have one subplot or multiple ones? You are creating at least two plots in your code, while changing the underlying DataFrame. Try just `df.plot(x='Datetime',y='calls')` and then `plt.show()` and see if that works.

Comment: And your Edit 3 suggests that one of the plotted columns is a string, I could imagine your Datetime is some string (like `2022-05-18` or so), in this case converting it to float wont really work or at least leave behind something that you don't cant interpret numerically. Can you give us an example of what the rows in the `Datetime` and inside the `calls` columns look like?

Comment: Can you print the first lines in the dataframe with `print(df.head())`? And what's the result of `df.dtypes` (check data types)?

Comment: date time calls
9/22/2021 12:43:54 75
5/14/2021 12:27:21 24
2/26/2021 12:03:51 41
6/25/2021 12:05:23 7
5/18/2021 11:40:13 60
11/2/2021 11:56:28 79
11/22/2021 14:23:59 33
8/2/2021 13:38:59 32
1/5/2021 11:50:41 52

Comment: @ewz93 My knowledge of Python is essentially 0.  I am trying to create a line graph that has date and time with amount of calls. How that is done, I have 0 idea hence why I am trying this.

Comment: You should try to just do string to date conversion exactly once and only do the `plot()` part exactly once. Seeing your code example I could imagine this is what causes the problems. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `to_datetime()` you can specify which string format you wish to convert to Dates. The one you provided should actually be interpreted correctly in any case though. I think in this case you shouldn't use `parse_dates` (or at least do not do both).

Here is a simplified example:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.DataFrame({"Datetime": ["4/23/2021 12:43:54", "7/24/2021 10:43:54", "9/27/2021 08:43:54", "9/30/2021 11:43:54"],
                       "calls": [76, 12, 1, 53]})
df["Datetime"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df.plot(x="Datetime", y="calls")
plt.show()
```

[image]

In your case you would replace the `df = ...` with just `df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\cbordelon\\Documents\\Python\\testcr1.csv', names=headers)`. So you wouldn't do the `parse_dates` or converting to `float` because this code expects exactly these string inputs in this format.

###### Edit:

Modified for your usage:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

headers = ['calls','date','time']
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\cbordelon\\Documents\\Python\\testcr1.csv', names=headers)
df["Datetime"] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']
df["Datetime"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df.plot(x="Datetime", y="calls")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did just that @ewz93 and received NameError: name 'headers' is not defined. I copy pasted your example and that was the output. I am sorry for the handholding, I normally handle the hardware and minor networking issues here. This is completely new to me and was thrust in my lap under protest.

Comment: I tried adding something to names=header and I received SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: You need to put your headers into this list, check my edit.

Comment: In Python you can use parameters for a method explicitly by using the parameter name and `=`, e.g. `read_csv(file_name='file.csv')` or implicitly if you just follow the order of the expected parameters, e.g. `read_csv('file.csv')`. For implicit you have to follow the expected order exactly, for explicit you can give it in any order you want. What is not allowed is that you first put an explicit parameter and then an implicit one, so you get the `Positional argument follows keyword argument` error message.

Comment: This is what I got after I ran the code you listed.
TypeError
    509 try:
--> 510     values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    511     dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
--> 7 df["Datetime"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

I am at a loss. I have no idea what I am doing. I am reading so much at night trying to learn this to keep my job.

Comment: It seems some of the input can't be properly converted to Datetime. There is just something wrong with your date column. You are making it a bit hard for us to help because we still don't know how exactly your `df["Datetime"]` looks. The column has to be in exactly the format as my first code sample: `["4/23/2021 12:43:54", "7/24/2021 10:43:54", "9/27/2021 08:43:54", "9/30/2021 11:43:54"]`. Any variations/empty rows/NA values etc. and the conversion won't work. Can you try to `print(df["Datetime"])` before the `pandas.to_datetime(...)` part and show us what it returns?

Comment: I stayed up to 2am last night and something worked. I posted the answer. It plots out a simple line graph which my boss enjoyed. Unfortunately, I think he wants more of this stuff and to use it to graph 2.5 years of call center data.

Comment: Yeah that seems straight forward and looks good to me. Although `df['date'].astype(str)` etc. do not work inplace. So if you do `df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)` something might happen if the previous content was not all strings. If you just use it like you did, this line has no effect. So you can probably just leave these lines out entirely. I assume there was a problem in the first or second row that was not a proper Datestring and caused all the problems, so using skiprows solved it?

Comment: Also, I'm really not trying to be a smartass or anything but if you next time include the content of your DataFrame in your question this would probably be the first thing that each answer would have suggested as this is a very common problem. And as a tip if you struggle with data read from an Excel I personally often just manually clean up the file beforehand instead of trying to solve it all in Python. Like making sure the headers are correct, the table is aligned etc., this usually helps me to solve this kind of problems before they even occur.

Comment: No offense, taken. I am a completely ignorant when it comes to this coding stuff. I am no excel or coding expert, however I have been thrust into it. I have no idea on establishing data models or any of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

headers = ['date', 'time', 'calls']

df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\Users\\cbordelon\\Documents\\Python\\testcr2.csv', names=headers, skiprows=1)
    
df['date'].astype(str)
df['time'].astype(str)

df["datetime"] = df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']

df["datetime"] = pandas.to_datetime(df["datetime"], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

df.plot(x="datetime",y="calls", kind="line")
plt.show()
```